# React onClick event on <svg/> not working

Tags: reactjs, svg, onclick

I'm trying to attach a onClick event on a svg icon.
I left out the unnecessarysvg pathfill code below but I tried to attach a onClick event and to test it right now the onClick event just triggers a log in console but it is not logging anything when I click the icon. Is it maybe not possible to attach an event directly to a svg?

```
<svg class="bi bi-gear" onClick={console.log('click')} width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   > </svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your onClick like that.

```
<svg class="bi bi-gear" onClick={() => {console.log('click')}} width="1em" height="1em" 
viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   > </svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've just made the switch from angular to react and it has taken me some time to adjust. It works perfect now!